# Selecting Contigous Range from two long data type

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a contigous range using two long data types but i kept getting and error 1004.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, "S").Column

    ***Range("rRow", "rCol").Select***

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("rRow", "rCol").Select` Not a correct way of selecting range.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I don't know how to select a Contiguous cell from Long data type.

Comment: I have added the ans. @Jude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA doesn't accept Variables in inverted commas, those are used for String insertions. Variables are passed without commas. Like in the below code.

Use this:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, "S").Column

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    'Refer to you worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column A (Based on the example answer is 4)
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Find last column of row 5 (Based on the example answer is 7)
        lCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Range select
       .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select

    End With

End Sub
```

**Images:**

[image]